# XCode Header Ctrl Drag

Tags: xcode

When I Control Drag an outlet from a MKMapView to my header file - XCode 4.5.2 does not automatically add the #import for the MapKit/MapKit.h

I have to manually add this -

Is there a way XCode can automatically add the header file

Comment: You don't want to `#import` in your header file in this scenario anyway. You want to use `@class MKMapView;`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The only code control-dragging will create are IBOutlets & IBActions.